# Translating Bash to Perl

Tags: bash, perl, if-statement, conditional-statements, system

I am rewriting a bash script in Perl.

The original script checks to see whether a Linux package is in an *unconfigured* state, and deletes and reinstalls it if so.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(dpkg -l | grep libc-bin | grep iF) || $(dpkg -l | grep libc-dev-bin | grep iU) ]] ; then
    echo "do something"
fi
```

I started to see if I could use system calls and store them as variables and then just run an `if` statement of these multiple variables. This did not seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $libcUnconfigured    = system("dpkg -l | grep libc-bin | grep iF");
my $libcDevUnconfigured = system("dpkg -l | grep libc-dev-bin | grep iF");

if ( $libcUnconfigured || $libcDevUnconfigured ) {
    print "Do something";
}
```

Comment: `system` returns the return code, not the output. Use `qx//` instead.

Comment: why are you using grep in perl?

Comment: Get package list: `my @libcUnconfigured = grep { /libc-bin|iF/ } qx(dpkg -l)`.  The `qx` ("backticks") returns a list, which `grep` filters and you get a list (array).  The `qx` uses `/bin/sh` or whatever the system supplies for it so you may need to specify the command path

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Why are you rewriting this shell script? It is counterproductive to just wrap `system(...)` around every line of the original code. Have you debugged the Perl code? Presumably `$libcUnconfigured || $libcDevUnconfigured` isn't returning what you expect, so what are those two values? What did you expect them to be? What does the documentation say about calls to `system`? If `system` is an acceptable approach then what's wrong with `system('./shellscript')`?

Comment: @zdim: If you're going to answer this dreadful question then please post an answer.

Comment: @Borodin Can't get to it now ... perhaps in an hour or a few unless somebody covers it by then. (It would be also nice to know from the OP whether that comment may be enough.)  Please by all means answer if you feel like it. sorry for the delay in responding

Comment: This is a bad idea to start with. Shell provides facilities for executing code safely -- if you have a name in a variable, you can refer to `"$var"` (in quotes), and be certain that it'll only evaluate to its literal contents -- no escapes, no redirections, no command substitutions or arbitrary code execution. When you start generating and executing shell scripts from other shell languages, you need to go to lengths to pass data out-of-band from code to keep those same security guarantees. Thus, wrapping shell scripts in other languages is inherently fault-prone, unless 100% hardcoded.

Comment: ...in the example given here that's true, but if the practice is continued it's unlikely to *remain* true for long. Still, though -- if you want to write a Perl script, why don't you *write a perl script* rather than a script that embeds a bunch of shell inside of Perl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to receive output from an external command use the [`qx` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), not [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) which returns the exit status of the program as returned by `wait`.

I suggest to use external programs only for things that you cannot do in Perl or, rarely, when they greatly simplify your work.  For all else use Perl's extensive processing capabilities.

In this case filter the return from `dpkg -l` by [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

```
my @libcUnconfigured = grep { /libc-bin|iF/ } qx(dpkg -l);

chomp @libcUnconfigured;

print "Do something with $_\n" for @libUnconfigured;
```

The `qx` returns a list of lines of output when used in [list context](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context), here imposed by `grep`. The code block in `grep` is run on an element at a time where each is available in the default [`$_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables); the regex match is by default done on `$_`. The items for which the code evaluates to true pass and are returned as a list, here assigned to an array.

Note that `qx` uses `/bin/sh`, generally relegated to another shell on your system. So put the command together carefully. See linked docs and [`$?` in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$?) for error checking.

Each line of output in the returned list comes with its newline, which I remove assuming some non-trivial processing with those filenames. (Wouldn't need to `chomp` for printing alone of course.)

Alternatively, you can reach for one of a number of modules.  A nice one is [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Capture-Tiny-0.44/lib/Capture/Tiny.pm)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my @cmd = qw(dpkg -l);

my ($stdout, $stderr) = capture {
    system (@cmd);
};

warn "Error with @cmd: $stderr" if $stderr;

say "Do something with $_" for (split /\n/, $stdout);
```

for its clean syntax, the fact that it hands us the error, and for its ability to run nearly any code

> Capture::Tiny provides a simple, portable way to capture almost anything sent to STDOUT or STDERR, regardless of whether it comes from Perl, from XS code or from an external program.

Here the command is formed as a list, what allows `system` to bypass the shell. This is better, unless you *need* the shell. The return in this case is a (possibly multiline) string which is thus [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to process lines with package information.

Some others, in increasing capability and complexity of use, are [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm) and [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm)

Also see [this entry in perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f). Note that [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html) used in some examples is rather low-level.